# How to get dynamically added editTexts values from android form?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Please refer following code:

for (Form form : formBody) {

```
        switch (Integer.parseInt(form.getFieldType())) {
            case 8:
                showDateTimePicker(form);
                break;
            case 3:
                showSingleTextBox(form);
                break;
            case 9:
                showRadioButtonWithQuestion(form);
                break;
            case 2:
                showSingleTextBox(form);
                break;
            case 4:
                showTwoRadioButtons(form);
                break;
            case 6:
                showRadioButtonsForRating(form);
                break;
            case 7:
                showRadioButtonsForRating(form);
                break;
            case 10:
                showSingleTextBox(form);
                break;
            case 15:
                showRadioButtonWithQuestion(form);
                break;
            case 17:
                showThreeCheckboxesWithThreeRadioButtons(form);
                break;
            case 18:
                show12TextBoxesWithThreeRadioButton(form);
                break;
            case 19:
            showOneEditTextWithThreeRadioButtonAndThreeEditText(form);
                break;
            case 20:
                threeCheckboxWithQuestion(form);
                break;
        }
    }
```

(Please refer above code)
So as mentioned above, I am dynamically adding Views in android LinearLayout (VERTICAL) and its working perfectly fine. But the problem I am facing is while getting the values after user clicks on Save Button. How will I get the values of each editText / checkbox, etc?

Comment: why don't save a reference to the added views somewhere?

Comment: Somewhere? Means where? Becuase I don't really know which view is going to come first. Based on the value of fieldType I am switching and adding layout dynamically.

Comment: "somewhere" maybe a Map<Integer, View>.When you add the view to the LinearLayout also save a reference into the map. When the user clicks on "save" you scroll the whole map and save the content of your views depending on their type (8 is a TimePicker, 3 is a TextBox, etc.)

Comment: But the fieldType is going to get repeated. Like 8 might come twice / four times maybe and so on and so fourth.

Comment: Ok, you can use a Map<Integer, Set<View>> and save multiple 8s or multiple 3s in the corresponding set

Answer (score 2):

Get the child view count from your Linear layout like below,

```
    int childcount = linearlayout.getChildCount();
```

based on child position you can get the view and view property like,

```
    for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
    View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
    EditText editText= (EditText) v;
    //get the text form edittext or checkbox here
    }
```

Comment: You means should I check if(v instance of EditText) then call get text method and so on?